# Is it possible to learn the functions using just header files?

Tags: function, header

In case of lack of proper updated tutorials for some particular library functions (in my case, latest allegro5), how can one learn by oneself how to call and use those functions? Is there some clue in header files?

thanks in advance

Comment: if the library is open source, then read the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header files are going to provide you with the bare minimum information required to correctly compile a program with those functions.  It has the types, constants, and function prototypes.  Nothing (short of comments) is going to explain how to correctly **use** the functions, just how to *call* them.

### General

For example, if you see:

```
int do_something(int n, const char* desc);
```

You can only infer that you need to pass an integer `n` and a (C) string `desc`.  That function returns an integer as well.

For a more complex example:

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
    double bar;
} blam_t;

void munge(blam_t info);
```

You know that `munge` takes one argument of type `blam_t` which is a custom structure, as defined above.  You *could* use that to create a `blam_t` variable and pass it to `munge()`:

```
blam_t myvar;
myvar.foo = 42;
myvar.bar = 0.67;

munge(myar);
```

### Allegro5

If we look at the source of [`include/allegro5/display.h`](http://alleg.de/gtags/S/1713.html) we see things like this:

```
AL_FUNC(void, al_set_new_display_flags, (int flags));
```

This is an uncommon way of defining functions. They are using a [macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion) AL_FUNC to define their functions.  We see (by clicking on it) that AL_FUNC is defined as:

```
#define AL_FUNC(type, name, args)               type name args
```

So that first example basically becomes:

```
void al_set_new_display_flags(int flags);
```

And we can call it with just an integer argument.

Without **any** documentation, you can only hope to learn by trying the functions.  Then this becomes more a reverse engineering task.